# Extract Array from another array using an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this

```
 $arr1 = Array('fn', 'ln', 'em');
 $arr2 = Array('fn'=>'xyz',  'ano' => 'abc', 'ln'=>'122', 'em' => 'a@b.com', 'db'=>'xy');
```

I want to create an array from arr2 with all the elements from $arr1. So the result should be like this.

```
 $result = Array( 'fn'=>'xyz', 'ln'=>'122', 'em'='a@b.com');
```

Don't want to loop.

Any idea?

Comment: "Don't want to loop." Why not?

Comment: @Rocket. I think there should be function that should be able to do this. Its a simple task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order of arguments is important here

```
 print_r(array_intersect_key($arr2, array_flip($arr1)));
```

Comment: @KevinRave: A up-vote is +10, you can also give it a +15 by marking it "accepted" (the checkmark under the votes) :-P

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_map` for this.

```
// PHP 5.3+ only
$result = array_combine($arr1, array_map(function($a) use($arr2){
    return $arr2[$a];
}, $arr1));
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y1aYcf

If you have PHP < 5.3, you can do some trickery with `array_intersect_key` and `array_flip`.

```
$result = array_intersect_key($arr2, array_flip($arr1));
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/MuydURQT

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop, as in create a new array or maybe check some array set in mathematics functions.  I think, maybe, insection might work.